# When loading a page, or any other page, I cannot stop the page load and navigate elsewhere

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, asynchronous

On my website when loading a page where Ajax take approx 2 to 5 mins to finish, or any other page, I cannot stop the page load and navigate elsewhere.

For example,
i load a page, but it takes 5min to load
I try to cancel, I hit X button in chrome
I click Home logo to navigate to home page
nothing loads
It's as if my browser is still stuck loading all the data from the page, even though I canceled it.
This happens all the time, especially for the page taking lots of time in Ajax. Can anyone guide me how i can fix it

Meanwhile, the ajax is loading if i use a different browser than the pages load fine but the different tab of the same browser does not work.

I am running PHP Laravel application, while both Apache and MySQL hosted on separately on multiple instances on Amazon.

Comment: seems like infinite loop is there in your code

Comment: no. there is no infinite loop. Request do complete but i know the data loading takes some time and this is historical data. The only problem is i can not cancel it and move to another page while loading

Comment: post your code for us to debug